# Coloring the borders of D3.js Sunburst visual

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Working with **D3 Observable Sunburst** visual like [this one](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst).

I need to **color the borders** between paths.

I can add **stroke** coloring where the path is defined:

```
 const path = g.append("g").selectAll("path").data(root.descendants().slice(1)).join("path")
 .style("stroke", "red")
```

...but it gives this:

[image]

I can create a **function** that uses a **condition**:

```
.style("stroke", function(d) {
    if(typeof(d.children) !== 'undefined') {
        return("red")
    }
})
```

...but gives incomplete bordering:

[image]

How can I color the borders around all paths?

Comment: Use the `arcVisible` function to define the border in the original rendering and in the transition: https://observablehq.com/d/7130ebd1199481a0

Comment: No difference. And link doesn't work.

Comment: Let me make the observable public: https://observablehq.com/@mortonanalytics/zoomable-sunburst. And I'm sorry it didn't work perfectly however you did it. I had intended you to get the working example with the code.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Add as answer if you want the points.

Comment: All I did was re-use Bostock's function that was already there! But thanks! Happy coding

Comment: Oh, and I'd replace the `"white"` with `"none"` in the stroke functions.

Comment: Thanks, I just used transparent.